# Multiple Choices - broken link

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, server

I uploaded a new website at the same place the old one was (I deleted the old one). When I type the address of my site in browsers url (www.mywebsite.net) it works just fine. But when I type "mywebsite" in google and click on the first result, it says:

Multiple Choices

The document name you requested (/index.php/) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/index.html/?language=hr (common basename)
Please consider informing the owner of the referring page about the broken link.

Does it have something to do with the .htaccess file? I tryed changing it didn't help. Both index.html and .htaccess are in the root.

Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Google doesn't actually have anything to do with it - find out the exact url that the Google listing is linking to and go from there. Could be an https issue or a www/non-www issue.

Comment: So you are telling me when i submit my new url to google 
(https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)
it will appear when they approve it?

Answer (score 0):

What is the default file for your **new** site? According to the error, index.php **used** to be the default file when only the directory was specified in the GET request. Now it seems you use index.html as your default file, so Google has not yet updated its indexes to recognize index.html instead of index.php. If that desperate, you can rewrite /index.php and redirect it to /index.html in the .Htaccess file.

Comment: That's exactly right. index.php was the default file before, and now I need it to be index.html. This is what I have in my .htaccess right now:

<code> RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.lay-z\.net
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.lay-z.net/$1 [R=301,L] </code>

Sorry to bother you, but I can't see what to change here..